# Substracting two pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I try to substract two pandas series which contain no. of flights for each day between passed dates. When i substract them i get series with length 132858. Why is that? I'd like to substract every paired date.

```
flights2019 = flights('2019-01-01','2020-01-01')
flights2020 = flights('2020-01-01','2021-01-01')
flightsDiff = flights2019.sub(flights2020)
print(flightsDiff.size)
```

Edit: My series seem to not be numbered. Could this be source of the problem? How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: What is `flights()`? By "subtract dates" do you mean determine the time interval in days between two dates? Please see [mcve].

Comment: flights() is a function that gets data from local database.
I receive number of flights for each day and i would like to get the difference of no. of flights for each day between 2020 and 2019

Comment: pandas aligns indexes when subtracting and 363*366 = 132858.

Comment: How do you plan to subtract two series with different length? What's your expected output?

Comment: It seems like I don't have data for two days in 2019. I'll check it out. Afaik it should still subtract if they're indexed - it then subtracts based on indeces and if no pairing for index can be found the value won't be subtracted by anything

Comment: Yeah but the index of both seems to be all zeros, hence 363*366.

Comment: If you do `flights2019 = flights2019.reset_index(drop=True)` and the similar for the other one, the result might be more meaningful. This resets the index to 0..N-1.

Comment: Yeah, index array wasn't configured. Thank you!